# Missing Android Studio uninstall.exe

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, sdk

I am having some issues with my download of Android Studio. I recently was on a test build Windows 11 and the Virtual Device Manager in Android Studio was not working. I found out that that build I was on was having issues with Android Studio so I reverted back to Windows 10. I had to do a complete reboot so I redownloaded Android Studio. I started getting issues with the SDK not wanting to download. I would select one in the SDK Manager and it would say that the file directory that stored the SDK was missing or corrupt. I have tried to uninstall in Settings but it tells me that uninstall.exe is missing. I downloaded a second version in hopes that it might have the uninstall.exe but it does not. What are my options to first get rid of my corrupt version and also install it correctly?

Comment: The answer to this problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087412/could-not-find-uninstall-exe-android-studio