# could not find uninstall.exe android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am new to Android Studio, however I am unable to change the background color of buttons. My guess is tat I'm dealing with a faulty installation.. I tried to uninstall Android Studio, but the uninsall.exe file seams to be missing:

[image]

How can I uninstall Android Studio without an uninstaller?

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the search engine in the file explorer. Enter the name of the program to remove and delete the directories that will appear.
2. Another way:-

- Press Windows key + R
- Then copy this string
  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\uninstall.exe

3. Third option is:-

- Search in startup menu
  %userprofile%
- Then delete the a) .android, b) .androidstudio
- Then reinstall the android studio again.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same problem. The main problem seems to be that the recent versions of Android Studio don't come with the `uninstall.exe` in the `C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudio` folder.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Download an older version of Android Studio. You can do that from the [Android Studio downloads archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).
2. Install it (preferably only the bare minimum as we are going to uninstall it anyway).
3. Go to the folder where you installed this version of Android Studio - you will find an `uninstall.exe` here.
4. Copy the `uninstall.exe` from that directory to `C:\ProgramFiles\Android\AndroidStudio`(the original one).
5. Run the uninstaller and this should solve the problem.

Comment: This did it for me, until I tried to just upgrade to latest version of android studio because gradle was too high of version.. redoing whole project.. but this should probably be reported to Android Studio devs.. along with how latest version breaks adb connection.

Comment: Instead of installing a new version, you can simply download the zip archive (instead of the installer) of an old version then extract only the `uninstall.exe` file.

Comment: To add to @Otiel's comment, I could find `uninstall.exe` on version [Android Studio ZIP v3.5.2](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.5.2.0/android-studio-ide-191.5977832-windows.zip)